# Benchmark tools for Soft-RoCE

Tags: infiniband, rdma

I am new to SoftRoCE, I have installed OFED-1.5.2-rxe in my system. currently using kernel version 3.0.0+.

Is there any **specific benchmark tools for SoftRoCE**. And is opensm is mandatory for SoftRocE? while i am trying to run rdma_bw

`vvdn@vvdn:~$ sudo rdma_bw 192.168.1.1`

`10581: | port=18515 | ib_port=1 | size=65536 | tx_depth=100 | sl=0 | iters=1000 | duplex=0 | cma=0 |
10581:main: Local lid 0x0 detected. Is an SM running?
vvdn@vvdn:~$`

Comment: I don't think you need an SM.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a SM.

Do you have a rdma_bw server running @ 192.168.1.1?  Also, I do not know if that is an example but usually I would avoid using that particular address since it is often the default for many network devices.